# Is this use of the progressive authentic (i.e. idiomatic)?

Tags: past-tense, progressive-aspect, grammar-myths

There is general consensus that

> I have been waiting for you for 6 hours.

is grammatically correct, and idiomatically authentic.  For example, our appointment was for 9 am, and when you show up at 3 pm, I tell you how long I've been waiting for you.

There is another sentence sometimes attempted by English language learners for the same situation:

```
It's been 6 hours since I was waiting for you.
```

**Does this sentence work in the 9am appointment, 3 pm arrival situation?**

(This question is motivated by [Meaning: "waiting for 6 hours" vs. "6 hours since I was waiting"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65151/meaning-waiting-for-6-hours-vs-6-hours-since-i-was-waiting/65285#65285) and a concern that English language learners might not capture just how rarely the since-progressive construction would be usable in English.)

Comment: You've excluded the main crux of the concepts in the answers you disagree with... the fact that the person was supposed to arrive at 9... the other person waited some (unspecified) amount of time and then left... and then the tardy arrival asked at a later time "are you still waiting for me?"... at, say 5 PM. No one in the other topic said that the two sentences you have here **mean** the same thing.

Comment: @Catija - This question is based on the Question I cited, not the answers.  My motivation: years of hearing non-native speakers of English trip up on this very construction.  If there is some other question that you think should be asked, I would invite you to post it!

Comment: If that's the case, how is this not simply a duplicate of the other question? Everyone on the other question says "no, it does not mean what you want it to mean"...

Comment: This question is about what is idiomatic (authentic), and is intended as a pedagogical tool for ELLs.

Comment: @aparente001: *All* questions are intended for that purpose. If it's a dupe, it's a dupe.

Comment: The suspected duplicate is asking a different question -- whether two sentences mean the same thing.  That's not what I'm asking here.  I'm asking whether a sentence is authentic and natural.

Answer (score 3):

If we wanted to say "six hours have elapsed since I decided to stop waiting for you" then the following is an unlikely choice:

**It's been 6 hours since I was waiting for you.**

Rather, we'd say something like:

**I stopped waiting for you six hours ago.**

because "since" needs a point-in-time not a span of time, and "coercing" the progressive semantically into a point-in-time expression is an "iffy" undertaking.

Answer (score 1):

**No, the past progressive is not appropriate for this situation.**

The past progressive comes in handy when you want to provide a descriptive backdrop for something dramatic to happen.  For example,

> Two weeks ago, I was sitting at my kitchen table having lunch with my brother, when the house began to shake and crockery started falling off the shelves.

You are best sticking with

> I have been waiting for you for 6 hours.

Now, suppose you give up on the person and leave the meeting place, and then he calls you later to complain that you weren't there when he showed up at 3:30, you can say

> I waited for you for 6 hours.